# How to GET POST DATE REST API in COdeigniter?

Tags: php, rest, python-requests, codeigniter-3

I am New in `REST` API.I have create an application of `REST Api` with `Codeigniter` 
but its gives the error. Please help me to remove error.

Controller:-

```
<?php
```

require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Example_api extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}

 function user_get($this->get('id'))
{
    if(!$this->get('id'))
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 400);
    }

    $user = $this->user_model->get_user($this->get('id'));

    if($user)
    {
        $this->response($user, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);
    }
}



function users_get()
{
    $users = $this->user_model->get_all();

    if($users)
    {
        $this->response($users, 200);
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);
    }
}
```

}

Model:-

```
<?php
```

class User_model extends CI_Model{

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();        
}

  public function get_user($id){
    $q=$this->db->get_where("employee",$id);
    return $q->result_array();
  }

  public function get_all(){
    $q=$this->db->get("employee");
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

}
?>

Error While Testing in Post Man Api:-

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>
<p>Type: ParseError</p>
<p>Message: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')'</p>
<p>Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\Api\application\controllers\Example_api.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 15</p>
<p>Backtrace:</p>
<p style="margin-left:10px">
        File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Api\index.php
    <br />
        Line: 315
    <br />
        Function: require_once
</p>
```

Comment: `function user_get($this->get('id'))`: I believe the problem is with this line. How are you trying to receive the function's argument here?

Comment: @TheNavigat how can i write this.